# Scheduling method run at exact time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm looking to schedule a method to run at an exact time selected by the user, and end at a time selected by the user. The user selects a time in the setup phase of my application and that value is stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

I then want the application to execute the method at the selected time which will also then end at a selected time.

I have seen a lot of people suggesting using `UILocalNotifications` but that is now deprecated in iOS 10. `NSTimer` is also suggested quite frequently but more often than not it is shot down for not being accurate enough.

What would be my best approach to implement this?

Comment: Check `UNUserNotificationCenter ` http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_10_Local_Notification_Tutorial

Comment: Yes, in iOS 10, see [UserNotifications.framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications?language=objc) or the WWDC 2016 [notifications video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/). Note, this can be used to present UI at a designated time, but not to automatically start and stop processes. Only if the user choses to open the app as prompted by the notification can you start the process. If you could be more precise regarding what this process that runs at these particular times, we can probably advise you better.